# Capacitor on power supply

Tags: power-supply, capacitor, safety

I included a 1000uF electrolytic capacitor on the power supply input in a circuit I built. I just noticed I placed it before the main on/off switch of the circuit, instead of after.
[image]

I plan on changing the position of the cap, to after the switch, but this would require disassembly of the housing, so I would rather wait until my next round of changes (in a few months).

Is there any problems leaving the cap where it is for a few months?  My feeling is that there are no issues, such as wasted current flow, danger, or instability.  The only issue is that the current position of the cap will do nothing to suppress inrush current when the circuit is turned on.

Is this correct?  Thanks in advance.

Edit:
The circuit I am driving is a controller and strips of APA102 LEDs, drawing a maximum of 6A.

This from the NeoPixel Uberguide: "Before connecting a NeoPixel strip to ANY source of power, we very strongly recommend adding a large capacitor (1000 µF, 6.3V or higher) across the + and – terminals. This prevents the initial onrush of current from damaging the pixels."

I guess my question has changed to: Do I need the 1000uF capacitor at all, or does introduce further complication?

Comment: if you put it after the switch you may find that you need a tougher switch.

Comment: What is "...the current position of the cap will do nothing to suppress input current..." supposed to mean?

Comment: I meant inrush current.  Sorry. I corrected this in the question.  I am trying to protect the LED strip from damage by the inrush current from the power supply.  I have read this is important to do.  Is it not?

Comment: @Jasen what do you mean?

Comment: @Fed if you have a big discharged capacitor, a switch and a power supply in a mesh, once you close the switch, the instantaneous current will be V/R, where V is the power supply voltage and R is the parasitic + initial contact resistance. R could be very small, therefore the current and instantaneous power will be very large. Therefore you need more rugged/robust contacts, otherwise the contacts will wear-out over time. Or they could even weld together.

Answer (score 1):

Typically you would not like to switch big loads using mechanical switches, as they bring several problems. In particular, contact wearout due to inrush currents. This problem is exacerbated in presence of capacitive loads. When you turn-on a capacitive load, you'll get a large inrush current. Rugged contacts are needed to handle that current. This would be the case in which the capacitor is after the switch.

This is also the case the pdf you linked suggests. In fact, they want you to put that capacitor in parallel to the strip, so that the voltage at the strip will not increase abruptly when you connect that strip to the PSU (i.e. when you turn on the switch). With that big capacitor, the voltage at the strip will rise with a time constant, which is C * R, where C is 1000uF, and R is the wiring resistance + contact resistance + PSU output resistance (* see note).

If you don't put such large capacitor, the voltage at the strip could rise "instantaneously". This would create an inrush current on the strip, which could be very high. In fact, for each LED (see pdf) a 100nF decoupling capacitor is mounted. Since the LED density might be as high as 144 LEDs/meter, you would have 14.4uF per meter. Say you have 1 meter, so 14.4uF. If the voltage rises with a 14.4us time constant (this automatically implies a total parasitic resistance of about 1 Ohm. I guess this is too much), you'll have a spike with an initial inrush current (I=C * dV/dt) of Vdd*C/Tau = 5 * 14.4uF/14.4us = 5A. This is an additional current, which must be added to your load current, and could damage something (the strip traces). 
If you put that additional 1000uF capacitor, the voltage will rise with a much slower rate (dv/dt). There will be also a much larger current spike, but not in the LED stripe, but between the PSU and the capacitor.

However, if you put that big capacitor AFTER the switch, the inrush current could damage over time:

1) the power supply;

2) the capacitor;

3) the switch (as a large spark will occur when contacts close).

If you want, consider using a pMOSFET/integrated Load Switch, where you can easily select the turn-on/turn-off times, then drive it with a smaller/cheaper switch. In that way, you can limit the inrush current. Just as an example, look at the application circuit of Si1865 http://www.vishay.com/docs/71297/si1865dl.pdf. Of course you must choose a load switch or mosfet that can handle that current (therefore the SI1865 won't suit your needs).

Leaving that big capacitor as it is now, it's even much more deleterious than not having it at all, because you're even reducing the PSU output impedance.

Notes:
 * you must include the PSU output resistance when its output capacitor is much smaller than 1000uF.

Comment: Why is it strange?  Most commercial products have on/off switches on the electronic product, not before the power supply.  I guess I am missing something here. As far as the cap, I have read that this is important to protect LED strips.  Is that not the case?

Comment: This from the NeoPixel Uberguide: "Before connecting a NeoPixel strip to ANY source of power, we very strongly recommend adding a large capacitor (1000 µF, 6.3V or higher) across the + and – terminals. This prevents the initial onrush of current from damaging the pixels."

Comment: @Fed The OP's comment about the LED protection was made few minutes ago. The answer was edited about 1 hour ago. 

About "most of the commercial products [...]", while I agree that in many commercial products, the external power supply has no power switch, you should consider that in many cases, the "power-on" switch just drives the logic to turn on/wake up the circuit (see example in the answer), i.e. is not a series switch to the regulated power... Think about a PC: the pushbutton just tells the MB to short (and keep shorted) the green wire to ground an ATX PSU.

Comment: @Fed about the led current, now I realized why they ask to put a 1000uF cap, despite their device being voltage driven: it's just to make a voltage slowing rising (a slowing rising voltage reduces the current flowing in the strip, as it is C*dV/dt, where C is the capacitance - including internal bypass, if any- of the strip). That's a bad suggestion anyway... I would suggest a slowing rising Vdd instead.

Comment: I am the OP, actually.  In any case, I am getting more confused by your explanation.  I do agree about the increase of inrush by the 1000uF cap.  I changed the question to include the LEDs...

Comment: sorry, didn't look at the user name :) Excuses, my fault!

Comment: @Fed The manufacturer asks you to put that capacitor for this reason: the capacitor will have a very low impedance, therefore it will actually short out the power supply, and the voltage at the strip will increase a bit slower. (the capacitor will be charged with a time constant of C*R, where C is 1000uF, and R is the parasitic wiring resistance + PSU output resistance). 

Following your pdf, if you put the capacitor before the switch (as in the schematics), you're also worsening the things. Removing it would be better. 

I hope this clarifies better.

Comment: Is there a problem with leaving the power supply plugged in for a long time with the switch on my circuit off?

Comment: Well, nothing serious. Leaving the PSU on, without any load, will waste some power (even if it could be very small on a good PSU) and it will reduce the PSU lifetime (which could otherwise stay disconnected from the mains).  I will make some edits to the answer in few hours, as now it does not answer to the question.

Comment: I now understand what you are saying. Unfortunately, it is in direct opposition to instructions from Adafruit: https://github.com/ManiacalLabs/AllPixel/wiki/Installing-Optional-Components#21mm-dc-barrel-jack, and https://github.com/ManiacalLabs/AllPixel/wiki/Assembling-the-PowerTap.  In fact, they say "Regardless of the strip type, there isn't any harm in installing this capacitor."  Do you have any opinion on why they would say the cap is needed when it could injure the PSU?

Comment: "There isn't any harm in installing that capacitor" should be read: "for the strip". I agree. 
But I have taken a look at your links, and there is no power switch between the capacitor and the power supply. In fact, the circuit is intendet to be always on (if you want you turn off the LEDs by software. Or you turn off the PSU). So, in their case, there should be no any harm at all. If you want to put the switch between PSU and cap, make sure you get rugged switch, capacitor and PSU. In other words, they should be able to withstand the inrush current.

Comment: So, to summarize, are you saying my original up is correct as long as the PSU is always plugged in.  In addition, from your prior discussion, each time the PSU is unplugged and replugged, the inrush to the cap can damage the PSU or cap?  Also, keeping the PSU always will decrease the life of the PSU, and waste energy?